# Work done by Kinetic Friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, friction

Which of the following is true for a system comprising of two bodies in contact exerting frictional force on each other.

a)total work done by static friction on system is always zero

b)work done by static friction on a body is always zero

c)work done by kinetic friction is always

d)total work done by internal kinetic friction on whole system is always negative.

Here a and d correct options

Though i get why a) is correct and b) and c) are incorrect.But i believe d is incorrect.
because if the system consists of two blocks on top of each other where the top block is 1kg and bottom one is 2kg
Coefficient of friction is u and external force on top block is 1.25ug where g is acceleration due to gravity.

[image] Here i believe total work done by kinetic friction on both blocks should be positive.

Comment: Kinetic friction causes the system to lose energy in the form of heat. The mechanical energy must decrease.

Comment: (a) depends upon how you define the system